# Unable to Construct StringBuilder object with HTML elements in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, stringbuilder

I am creating `Dynamic HTML Table` Markup filled with the Data from `DataTable` using `C#`. I am using the `StringBuilder` object Built-up HTML markup. On compilation i am getting error "*Unable to Convert string to String builder*"

Code:

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
dt=GetData();
StringBuilder strDeviceList=new StringBuilder();
strDeviceList = "<table style='width:100%;text-align:center;'>" +
                            "<tr>" +
                                "<td> Quote ID</td><td>Device</td><td> Generation</td><td>Condition</td><td>Price</td>" +
                            "</tr>";                          
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                strDeviceList.Append("<tr>" +
                 "<td>" + row["QuoteID"] + "</td><td>" + row["Name"] + "</td><td>" + row["Generation"] + "</td><td>" + row["Condition"] + "</td><td>" + row["Price"] + "</td>" +
                 "</tr>");
            }
strDeviceList.Append("</table>");
```

Any idea?
Help Appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line, in your code you are trying to assign `string` to `StringBuilder`, that is reason of compilation error

```
strDeviceList.Append("<table style='width:100%;text-align:center;'>" +
                            "<tr>" +
                                "<td> Quote ID</td><td>Device</td><td> Generation</td><td>Condition</td><td>Price</td>" +
                            "</tr>");
```

or more cleaner

```
strDeviceList.Append("<table style='width:100%;text-align:center;'>");
strDeviceList.Append("<tr>");
strDeviceList.Append("<td> Quote ID</td><td>Device</td><td> Generation</td><td>Condition</td><td>Price</td>");
strDeviceList.Append("</tr>");
```

and you can use `AppendFormat` to append dynamic values with string

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    strDeviceList.AppendFormat("<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td><td>{3}</td><td>{4}</td></tr>",row["QuoteID"],row["Name"],row["Generation"],row["Condition"],row["Price"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strDeviceList = "...."; //wrong

strDeviceList.AppendLine("...."); //use this
strDeviceList.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", row["Name"]); //even smarter
```

one more thing is that StringBuilder .Append has better performance than string concatenation operator

```
//instead of native string concat
string str = "aaa" + "bbb" + "ccc";

//builder is faster when performing multiple string concat
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append("aaa");
builder.Append("bbb");
builder.Append("ccc");
string str = builder.ToString();
```